# Get back index of matched element?

Tags: selenium, xpath

Is there a way to get the index of the matched element f.e. let say I have a table and use the following xpath expression to find element by content :

```
 //table/thead/tr/th[contains(.,'blah')]
```

I want to know the index of the matched 'th' element ? i.e. was it the first cell or the second one .. or .. nth.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to implement below code (`Python` example):

```
all_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table/thead/tr/th')
target_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table/thead/tr/th[contains(.,"blah")]')
print(all_elements.index(target_element))
```

`Python` `list` has built-in method `index()` which allow to get index of element in a list. Let me know if you need a solution in another programming language

Comment: thanks , will try that. I'm doing it in java, but no need of example I got your point.  I was also wondering if there was a way to it purely in xpath, but even then i dont see how I can get back integer.  .findElement() returns webElement not integer.

Comment: Oh, I see... You can try to count a number of preceding elements : `count(//table/thead/tr/th[contains(.,"blah")]/preceding-sibling::th) `. This is pure `XPath` syntax

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same functionality in `ruby`. But in `Java` you can try something like this in `Java`:

```
String path = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th[contains(.,'blah')]")).toString();
String lastElement = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

And for getting count of your `th` I'm using following code in `ruby`:

```
int columnNo = lastElement .match(/(?<=\[).+?(?=\])/).to_s.to_i
```

You can use appropriate code in `java`. Please correct if any typecasting errors. I'm not a java guy.